# How to properly export and import NFS shares that have subdirectories as mount points also?

Tags: mount, nfs

Server `A` exports directory `/srv` via NFS with option `nohide`. A subdirectory within `/srv`, `/srv/foo`, is a mount point for another location on the NFS server using `--bind` option, like

> `server# mount --bind /bar/foo/ /srv/foo/`

Client `B` imports `A:/srv` and mounts it on `/mnt/srv` using NFS. Contents of `/mnt/srv` are the contents of `A:/srv`.

The problem is that `/mnt/srv/foo` is empty, while I'm expecting to see the contents of `A:/bar/foo/` there.

How to properly export and import NFS shares that have subdirectories as mount points also?

Comment: Maybe easier to just use symlink on A from `/srv/foo --> /bar/foo` ?

Comment: I tried this. This would try to get to the `/bar/foo` on client machine `B`, not on server `A`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks like every mount sub-point must be exported by the NFS server in order to be visible for clients. In the situation above the `/etc/exports` file should look like the following:

```
/srv        *(rw,fsid=0,nohide,no_subtree_check)
/srv/foo    *(rw,nohide,no_subtree_check)
```

Then, importing `/srv` on the client with option `-t nfs` will make both `/srv` and `/srv/foo` properly available.

#### edit by OP

this line

```
    /srv/foo    *(rw,fsid=0,nohide,no_subtree_check)
```

has worked in my case instead of

```
    /srv/foo    *(rw,nohide,no_subtree_check)
```

Comment: crossmnt  on the root?

Answer (score 48):

`crossmnt` is your friend.

```
/srv        *(rw,fsid=0,no_subtree_check,crossmnt)
```

Answer (score 12):

I had stumbled into this problem while following the [Diskless Arch](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Diskless_System) guide, and it really slowed me down.  I am going to share my findings here, as I am curious if this will work for anyone else.

As per the Diskless guide I have the diskless client's root filesystem (the actual data I need to export) in a loopback image, which has been mounted on `/srv/des1`:

```
/srv/des1.img on /srv/des1 type btrfs (rw,relatime,compress=lzo,discard,space_cache)
```

I then created a mountpoint `/nfs/des1` then run the mount, and confirm that I can see everything:

```
# mkdir -p /nfs/des1 
# mount --bind /srv/des1 /nfs/des1
# ls -l /nfs/des1
bin  boot  dev  usr  #[SNIP]
```

Referring to the [Arch NFS](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NFS) guide, I then put the following in `/etc/exports` on the server:

```
/nfs/      *(rw,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check,fsid=root)
/nfs/des1/ *{rw,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check,nohide)
```

I then ran an `exportfs -rav` on the server to apply these changes.

However I then mounted the share on the test client with: `mount server:/des1 /mnt/tmp` only to find it's an empty directory, when I expected the diskless-root-filesystem to be there.

At this stage I tried just about everything until something lead me to this option in the `exports` man page:

```
crossmnt
    This option is similar to nohide but it makes it possible for clients
    to move from the filesystem marked with crossmnt to exported filesystems
    mounted on it. Thus when a child filesystem "B" is mounted on a parent "A",
    setting crossmnt on "A" has the same effect as setting "nohide" on B.
```

So having tried everything else I swapped this around so my `/etc/exports` looked like this:

```
/nfs/      *(rw,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check,fsid=root,crossmnt)
/nfs/des1/ *{rw,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)
```

Having read the man page entry you would think this would have the same effect as the previous code, but when I ran `exportfs -rav` again to register the changes, then tried to remount from the client and it worked!

Comment: the crossmnt on my root folder (where a potential mount bind would be) fixed my "empty" folder bit. So I appreciate this answer very much. wish this answer got more to the top or the final fix was more upfront. (not sure if needed)

Comment: From the man page exports(1): "The nohide option is currently only effective on sigle host exports.  It does  not work  reliably  with netgroup, subnet, or wildcard exports."

Answer (score 4):

I really wanted to do this too, but it seems there are problems with this idea because the NFS clients expect inode numbers of files to be unique within the *client's* view of a single mount.

The problems are detailed in this blog post (not by me):  http://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/unix/MultiFilesystemNFSIssue

I've decided to mount the filesystems separately and symlink them together, which should work for all NFS clients.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

***NOTE:*** only single user enabled

What it adds is a set of edits to server side and client side. On the server side, `/etc/exports` and `/etc/fstab` on client side.

#### Server side

- Linux Mint 18.3 Sylvia 32-bit
- Kernel Linux 4.4.0-138-generic i686
- Asus eeepc

  ```
  $ cat /etc/exports 
  #insert shares (one for each mounted partition sub-folder):      
  /nfsshare/ /192.168.1.155(rw,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check,fsid=root,crossmnt)
  /nfsshare/media/ 192.168.1.155(rw,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)
  /nfsshare/extra/ /192.168.1.155(rw,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)   

  $ cat /etc/fstab  
  #shared media files on /media/ed/
  /media/ed/ /nfsshare/ nfs bind 0 0
  /media/ed/media/ /nfsshare/media/ nfs bind 0 0
  /media/ed//extra /nfsshare/extra/ nfs bind 0 0
  ```

#### Client side

- Linux Mint 19 Tara 64-bit
- Kernel Linux 4.15.0-38-generic x86_64

  ```
  $ cat /etc/fstab
  #NFS Shares line added
  192.168.1.158:/nfsshare /mnt/share nfs rw,soft,intr,noatime,x-gvfs-show
  ```

Comment: What is this? Is this one file? Many files? Please use the [formatting tools](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to format your answer for clarity.Could you please [edit] and explain how your answer answers the question?

Comment: (1) Use your words.  (2) What does this offer that hasn’t already been presented?

Comment: apologies for that .