# NFS Mount and Subfolders

Tags: nfs

I have problems with exporting NFS shares and accessing subdirectories.

I exported `/srv/nfs`, by adding this line to `/etc/exports`:

```
/srv/nfs/       *(rw,no_root_squash,fsid=0)
```

I can mount `/srv/nfs` and I can see the subfolder `P01`. However, under `P01` there are additional subfolders which I can´t see from the client. What I am doing wrong? Already tried several options like `Nohide`, but still no luck.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add: i) the details of how you are you mounting from the client. Is it manually with a `mount` command? Are you using `autofs`? Systemd? If so, add the relevant config files. Where are you mounting to? ii) what exactly happens when you try to access the share from the client. Does the `ls` give an error? Just no output? iii) the operating systems of both client and server.

Comment: On the server, is /srv/nfs/P01 on a filesystem that's different from /srv/nfs ? If so, one of the answers in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42131/how-to-properly-export-and-import-nfs-shares-that-have-subdirectories-as-mount-p may help you.